# Why is this Javascript disabling only nested view forms?

Tags: javascript, c#

We have a C# application where I am using nested views to display user form data. I want to disable the nested form and keep another form on the page enabled. Everything is working as intended but I don't understand why.

The nested view - to be disabled.
`@Html.Partial("~/Views/Folder/TheView.cshtml", Model)`

The on page form - to keep enabled.
`@using (Html.BeginForm("Modify", "Controller", FormMethod.Post))`

The script disabling
        `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () { $("#Form *").prop("disabled", true); });`

All of the checkboxes/textboxes on "TheView.cshtml" are disabled, however my on page form is not.  I can't figure out why this is not disabling all DOM form elements and only those in the nested views and I can't find information on what $("#Form *") is retrieving and why. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: `"#Form *"` is a selector that matches all children of the element with the ID of `"Form"`. So only those will be disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selector is not selecting your "Form"; you are actually selecting any element with an id of '`Form`'.

So you would select this:

```
<div id="Form">Some Content</div>
```

but not this:

```
<form>form content in here</form>
```